# In Rails I want to read excel file form Live Path like http://www.carsa.jp/admin/data.xlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, rubygems

I wants to read a excel file existing on Live URL of another website.

When I hit that URL in browser file is downloading. While in my rails app it is giving below error

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://www.carsa.jp/admin/data.xlsx (Errno::ENOENT)
```

My Rails app code is as below

```
data = Roo::Excelx.new('http://www.carsa.jp/admin/data.xlsx')
header = data.row(1)
puts header
```

**Note:**  If I download file and place it within my application it is working fine but the requirement is to read it from the third-party website in a scheduled job as per the above script.

```
data = Roo::Excelx.new('lib/data.xlsx')
header = data.row(1)
puts header
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Roo::Spreadsheet.open` instead of `Roo::Excelx.new`. According to the [Roo Readme:](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#usage)

> Roo::Spreadsheet.open can accept both paths and File instances.

This should do the trick:

```
Roo::Spreadsheet.open('http://www.carsa.jp/admin/data.xlsx')
```